# Captcha with numbers only

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha

I am currently building a Wordpress plugin - it is basically a simple form with validation, that submits to the database, the Wordpress dashboard and sends the admin an email containing the message submitted into the form.

Everything mentioned above works well. It is functioning as it should. However I now want to add captcha to the contact form to keep it as spam proof as possible.

I have been looking into contact forms on other websites and I seen one that uses images with numbers on them instead of numbers itself - the numbers are 1-9 and the 5 images change each time.

Has anyone any idea on how to code something similar in PHP or have links to any good tutorials - I have searched the web but have found nothing useful - I think this example I found is in ASP.net. I have included link to website below.

http://www.whatglasses.com/pages/index.asp?title=Contact_Us

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Captcha tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkNucufSyXY) this could be really helpful for what you are looking for :)